# MySQL - Error: Missing right parenthesis

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I'm trying to create a new table called SITANAG with SQLTalk for Window. When i execute this command:

```
CREATE TABLE SITANAG
(
   ANAGCOD INT NOT NULL UNIQuE,
   PRIMARY KEY(ANAGCODE)
);
```

I get this error:

```
ANAGCOD INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                     ^
Error: Missing right parenthesis
```

Someone know why this give error?

**Thank for your time**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont have to make the column as NOT NULL and UNIQUE explicitly. Primary key is by default NOT NULL and UNIQUE. Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE SITANAG
(
   ANAGCOD  INT, 
   PRIMARY KEY(ANAGCOD )
);
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25eca8)**

*On a side note you have a typo error when you are naming your column in primary key, it should be either ANAGCOD or ANAGCOD**E***

The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html#id879566) says:

> A PRIMARY KEY is a unique index where all key columns must be defined
>   as NOT NULL. If they are not explicitly declared as NOT NULL, MySQL
>   declares them so implicitly (and silently).

Comment: Now it give this error                                                                                                         PRIMARY KEY(ANAGCOD)
 ^
   Error: Primary key column must be NOT NULL or NOT NULL WITH     DEFAULT

Comment: @AndreaFino:- I am not sure what you are trying as the query which I have added should work. Also if you want then you can add the NOT NULL like this `CREATE TABLE SITANAG
(
   ANAGCOD  INT NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY(ANAGCOD )
);`

Comment: If I put NOT NULL it works but when I try to execute a simple insert like this  INSERT INTO SITANAG (ANAGCOD) VALUES(1) it give me an error like this Table SITANAG in incomplete state

Comment: Yes me too, but I'm executing it on SQLTalk for windows.